# AngularJS doesn't display MySQL results *edited

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

The view for an overview (root.html) of MySQL data doesn't show data. Opening /php/overview.php however indicates that the data could be fetched correctly:

> Connection to MySQL server successful. [{"Job_title":"flash","Job_id":"doggg"},{"Job_title":"ad34","Job_id":"teeee"}]

root.html

```
<table class="setup-table">
    <tr>
        <td>Job title</td>
        <td>Job ID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
        <td>A {{campaign.Job_title}}</td>
        <td>B {{campaign.Job_id}}</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

controller.js (Note that the alert "It WORKED (DELETE Later)" shows up, but the table in the view is empty:

```
ctr.controller
('RootCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http)

                {

                    $http.get("php/overview.php")
                        .then(function successCallback(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            $scope.campaigns = response.data;
                            alert("It WORKED (DELETE ME)");

                        }
                        , function errorCallback(response) {
                            $scope.campaigns = "error in fetching data";
                            alert("DID NOT WORK ");}
                            )
                        ;}

                ]);
```

overview.php

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');

$query = "SELECT Job_title, Job_id FROM campaign";
$result = $connect->query($query);
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($data);
mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the data received? Is it what you expect? Do you see correct template in `ng-view`? Not much detail given regarding your problem

Comment: add a `$scope.$apply();` ?

Comment: The array is empty is what i am guessing.. can you print the $scope.campaigns

Comment: I have added console log for data and campaigns but nothing appears in the firebug console. So it is empty I suppose.  
I'll add the php for writing content into the db.

Comment: @YaeVo see my answer. It should be correct, despite the comments to the contrary.

Comment: Well if there was no content in db then that would clearly be a major issue. Create a static array to send to test front end with

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when you get a server route you receive a full response object in reply rather than just the requested data, so changing the section of your code that makes this call to look like this:

```
{
    $http.get("php/overview.php")
     .success(function(response){
         console.log(response);
         $scope.campaigns = response.data;
         alert("It WORKED (DELETE Later)");
      })
      .error(function() {
          $scope.campaigns = "Could not fetch data";
          alert("DID NOT WORK (DELETE Later");
      });
}
```

should do the trick. I also added a console.log call so you can inspect the response.

Note: success and error are deprecated. It's recommended that you use .then() in response to a $http call. The refactoring is very minor.

Comment: OP is showing the php code that generates the json. There is no object with `data` property. It is nothing but an array of objects. Don't guess...read the OP code

Comment: I don't do PHP, but when I hit a .NET site that also just writes JSON out I get a full response object back. I don't know why that wouldn't be the case here. Thanks for the lecture though. It's no wonder so many developers find this site a turnoff and are afraid to ask and answer questions. Per the angular doc OP should receive a response object with data, status, headers, statustext and config members. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: The angular $http function response always stores the data returned from the request in `response.data`. If the object had a data property, it would be accessed by `response.data.data`.

Comment: Exactly. Not sure why @charlietfl felt the need to lecture or down vote. He pretty much always knows what he's talking about. Must need coffee. :)

Comment: @MikeFeltman Thank you for the link, that made things a bit clearer! I changed the code accordingly but the table is still empty (edit in question above). I suspect the error to be in the php code somewhere.

Comment: You're welcome. Did you add the console.log and look at the results in the console? That would be the first step in seeing what's coming back from PHP.

Comment: this is the console log:

controllers.js:31 


Object {data: "<p>Verbindung zum MySQL Server erfolgreich aufgebaut.</p>No such file or directory", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: My Deutsch is pretty rusty, but that looks like some kind of error to me, even though you're getting a status of 200 back. You might just want to navigate to the URL in the browser and see what you're getting. At any rate, your client code is now correct. I'd recommend digging into the server side and opening a new question specific to it if you need further assistance.

Comment: The <p> message is an echo from the initiated db.php (which connects to the db) for a successful db connection. No idea why this is in the console.log (response) though (line31). I can also not explain where 'no such file or directory' comes from.

Comment: I don't PHP, but I would suspect: file_get_contents("php://input")

Comment: .Net has nothing to do with what OP is outputing as a simple array of objects which is extremely common output structure

Comment: @water....that is not true when using `success`...only when using `then`. OP's code was correct for receiving what is being sent when they were using `success` although it is deprecated

Comment: OP has already confirmed he is getting a full response object back.

Comment: yes, the response is not empty. I now receive an array as output on the overview.php (see recent edit). Yet, something in the AngularJS controller seems to be wrong, I just can't exactly figure out what.